# Mocha, "require is not defined" when test in browser

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha 5.2.0, npm 6.1.0, and I'm trying to test in Chrome browser.

But When I run the test, the browser says "require is not defined".

I want to see the test result in browser, but it works in terminal.

I'm not using build system like webpack etc.

**test/test.js**

```
var assert = require("assert");
    describe("Array", function() {
        describe("#indexOf()", function() {
            it("should return -1 when the value is not present", function() {
                assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
        });
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
...
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/5.2.0/mocha.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/5.2.0/mocha.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        mocha.setup("bdd");
    </script>

    <script src="test/test.js"></script>

    <script>
        mocha.checkLeaks();
        mocha.run();
    </script>
</body>
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha"
    }
}
```

**Edited** Karthikeyan

**index.html**

```
<script data-main="test/test.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "assert" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require.js is missing . Import require.js inside your body before importing mocha.js

Comment: Why need require.js? es6 supports it.

Comment: You are running the test in your browser and your browser javascript engine is throwing you the error require is undefined during run time. Can you try with importing require.js as I said and check if it works?

Comment: I thought **requiare** is supported by es6. hang on.

Comment: I did. now then **require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "assert" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])**

Comment: assert is Node.js built in module. So it does not work in browser. You can either use chai or some other assertion library. Go through this link 
https://mochajs.org/#running-mocha-in-the-browser

Comment: `require` is not a part of es6, never has been. es6 uses [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).