# Testing NodeJS with Mocha: 'Require is not defined'

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

EDIT:

As per the comment on the answer below: removing "type": "module" from `package.json`, which as I understand it is what makes Node understand 'import' and 'export' statements, and reverting everything to 'require' and 'module.exports' solved the issue.

Is there a way to keep 'import' and 'export' and still make Mocha work?

---

I have a very simple Node file that I'm trying to test with Mocha/Chai.  The actual code is trivial, this is just to learn a bit about Mocha and how to use it. But when I run the Mocha test, I get the error `ERROR: ReferenceError: require is not defined`
`

I did some googling for people experiencing the same problem but the examples that I came up with  were when they were running the test in the browser (see, for example, [Mocha, "require is not defined" when test in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673993/mocha-require-is-not-defined-when-test-in-browser)).

The file I want to test, `index.js`

```
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));


const digitTester = /\d/g;
const capTester = /[A-Z]/g;

const dict  = {
    length:10,
    must_have_numbers: true,
    must_have_caps: true
}

export default function passwordCheck(password) {
    if (!password) return false;
    if (typeof password !== "string") return false;
    if (password.length < dict.length) return false; // assumes that 10 is a MINIMUM length
    if (dict.must_have_numbers && !digitTester.test(password)) return false;
    return !(dict.must_have_caps && !capTester.test(password));

}
if (argv._.length) {
   console.log(passwordCheck(argv._[0]))
}

/**
 * alternate version to check a lot of passwords:
 *
 * if (argv._.length) {
 *  for (const pwd of argv_) console.log(passwordCheck(pwd)
 *}
 *
 */
```

the mocha file, `test/index.test.js`

```
const chai = require('chai')
const expect = chai.expect

const passwordCheck = require('../index.js')

const tooShort = "A2a"
const noCaps = "a2abcdefghijklmnop"
const noNumber = "Aabcdefghijklmnop"
const good = "A2abcdefghijklmnop"

describe('password checking', () => {
  it('should return false for passwords less than length 10', () => {
    expect(passwordCheck(tooShort)).to.be.false;
  });
  it('should return false for passwords without a capital letter', () => {
    expect(passwordCheck(noCaps)).to.be.false;
  });
  it('should return false for passwords without a number', () => {
    expect(passwordCheck(noNumber)).to.be.false;
  });
  it('should return true for passwords that match criteria', () => {
    expect(passwordCheck(good)).to.be.true;
  });

});
```

and `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "codetest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/minimist": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1"
  }
}
```

and the error message is

```
✖ ERROR: ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///Users/r/Documents/Projects/sandbox/pwd_checker/index.js:2:14
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:166:24)
    at async exports.handleRequires (/Users/r/Documents/Projects/sandbox/pwd_checker/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:94:28)
    at async /Users/r/Documents/Projects/sandbox/pwd_checker/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:341:25
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Node 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line -  "type": "module" from package.json and check whether it’s working or not.

Comment: Removing that line, which was what made Node understand 'import' and 'export' statements, and reverting everything to 'require' and 'module.exports' solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend your tests with the following:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

This is because you cannot require from an ESM module; for more info please see [this comment on a nodejs issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33741#issuecomment-639463213).

Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#differences-between-es-modules-and-commonjs